# Extracting a nested type from the generic parameter of a generic class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm working on a TypeScript project and I have a generic class `AbstractDAL` with a generic type parameter `T_DEFAULT_RETURN`. Inside the `AbstractDAL` class, I'm trying to extract a nested type that is specified within the `T_DEFAULT_RETURN` generic type parameter, but I'm facing some challenges.

Here's the simplified code structure I have:

```
class A {
    alpha() { }
};

class B extends A {
    beta() { }
};

abstract class AbstractDAL<
    T_DEFAULT_RETURN extends BaseEntity = BaseEntity,       
    T_DATA = T_DEFAULT_RETURN extends BaseEntity<infer D> ? D : never
> {
    get result() {
        return {} as T_DATA
    }
}

class BaseEntity<       
    T_DATA extends A = A
> { }



class TestDAL extends AbstractDAL<TestEntity> {
    delta() {
        this.result.alpha // should also be beta, not just alpha
    }
}

class TestEntity extends BaseEntity<B> { }
```

In the above code, the `AbstractDAL` class is defined with a generic type parameter `T_DEFAULT_RETURN`, and I'm trying to extract a nested type from this parameter. I have used a conditional type with infer and a helper type `T_DATA` to accomplish this. However, the inferred type for `T_DATA` is `A` instead of the expected type `B`.

Is there a way to correctly extract the nested type `B` from the `T_DEFAULT_RETURN` generic type parameter within the `AbstractDAL` class? If so, what modifications are needed in the code to achieve this?

Comment: This code is somewhat problematic:  [your `A` and `B` types are structurally identical to the empty type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces) and thus indistinguishable. And, the line `class TestEntity extends BaseEntity<typeof TestDAL, B> { }`  has a compiler error you're not asking about. Please [edit] to resolve these issues, so that the code is a [mre]. good luck!

Comment: @jcalz, I have rewritten my code, please take a look again

Comment: Now the issue seems to be that `BaseEntity<T>` is structurally independent of `T`. So you can't infer `X` from `BaseEntity<X>` consistently, just like you couldn't infer the input of `(x)=>3` from its output.  See [the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--). If you fix that somehow, say [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/wO56pm), things should work. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, it seems to me `declare d: D` did the magic! Could you please explain why it works now?

Comment: I will write up a full answer when I get a chance, but [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--) explains it, and I explained in my comment; if you want to infer `X` from `BaseEntity<X>` then `BaseEntity<X>` needs to have something that depends on `X` in its type definition. Does that make sense or are you still wondering?

Comment: @jcalz, it makes sense. But still it would be great if you wrote a complete answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `BaseEntity<T>` does not depend on `T` structurally, and thus inference from `BaseEntity<T>` to `T` is, at best, unreliable.

---

TypeScript's type system is largely [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  That means types are compared by their *structure* or *shape*, and not by what they are *named* or where they are *declared*.  If type `X` and type `Y` are both object types with the same members, then they are the same type:

```
interface X { w: string; z: number; }
let x: X = { w: "abc", z: 123 };

interface Y { w: string; z: number; }
let y: Y = { w: "def", z: 456 };

x = y; // okay
y = x; // okay
```

In the above it doesn't matter whether you use the name `X` or the name `Y` to refer to the type.  They are interchangeable.

This extends to [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) as well.  If you have a generic type that doesn't use its type parameter inside the type definition, like

```
interface F<T> { w: string; z: number }
```

then all types you create by specifying `T` with a type argument will be identical to each other, and thus interchangeable:

```
let fs: F<string> = x; // okay
let fn: F<number> = y; // okay
fs = fn; // okay
fn = fs; // okay
```

There is no difference between `F<string>` and `F<number>`, or between either of them and `X` or `Y`.  We don't care about the *name* `F<string>`, just the *shape* `{ w: string; z: number }`.

And that's indicative of a problem in the code.  [Type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html), such as what you get when [you use `infer` in a conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types), can only work consistently if it is inferring from *structure*.

Asking TypeScript "given `G<T>`, what type is `T`", the compiler cannot necessarily answer correctly.  It depends strongly on the definition of `G`.  For example, given our `F<T>` definition above, where `F<T>` is identical to `X` for all `T`, then the information you want is essentially gone.  If I asked you to tell me *which* `T` makes `F<T>` equal to `{ w: string; z: number }`, there's no principled away to answer.  Indeed any answer is equally correct.  There's no principled way to say that a particular `{ w: string; z: number }` came from `F<string>` vs `F<number>`.  Sometimes you'll find that the compiler does infer from names, but you can't rely on it.

So, in general, you should never have unused type parameters.  See the TypeScript FAQ entry [Why doesn't type inference work on this interface: `interface Foo<T> { }`?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).

---

The solution is therefore to add some structure to your type that depends on the generic type parameter.  A `BaseEntity<T>` should have something to do with `T`!  For example, if you add a property of type `T`, everything starts working:

```
class BaseEntity<D extends A = A> {
    declare d: D // <-- make it structurally dependent
}

class TestDAL extends AbstractDAL<TestEntity> {
    delta() {
        this.result.alpha
        //^? (property) AbstractDAL<TestEntity, B>.result: B            
    }
}
class TestEntity extends BaseEntity<B> { }
```

That [`declare` field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) is just me telling the compiler that a `BaseEntity<D>` has a field of type `D` at key `d` without having to actually initialize it.  In practice you should always initialize your class fields. The compiler will allow you to write `new BaseEntity<string>().d.toUpperCase()` but it will explode at runtime if `d` wasn't initialized.  I'm more worried about typings than initialization.

That's just an example.  You should try to give `BaseEntity<T>` some structural dependence on `T` that makes sense for the actual use case, and only resort to a "phantom" property like `declare d` if you really don't have anything better.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3&ssl=25&ssc=73&pln=24&pc=26#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XTCADgCzACgEpFoBfJEgbiSVEhgCFoBTADwBcmA7AExnmTTQARkzb4iCUuSpIwQiGwBOYYG2i0oceUpVsAIrAAyAHhRoASs3Zde0epCYBRTmwCWbAJ7QAvHYfO3TwAaM1Q9H2hLVg4eBn8Xdw9jV04AMyZFaAAVAD5oAH5s6AAuaE4mADcMpDyBNABzUWhFJggAVxA2QkRQwWbRNsVORBJ0GD1esjIacE17CCcEz2Nw6Js+CNha3u4mWhboblLwgHoT6GMAWkvoAFswAGsmaHdoBUU21UGMEC9dzBsXDY5GoGhgWVa+iMVhitlg2mUqgMJghCgCiW2gl2nXEPT6aDY2FcEAAdC12p0SRgcGBeoIzgA9Qp4TCKAD2AMUniI8PeumRxlRbHRwTsOTJrQ6bFKjHxfUmILB2UhIq8a1ifgWquM9FqUiQQA)